# Testing async state changes in react hook with react @testing-library/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

I have a react hook, that basically maintain loading state and data state and returns its current values. On initial load fetches some data a and sets data state and loading state. Very basic stuff.
Implementation looks like this:

```js
export const usePeopleListAPIService = ({requestQueryParams}) => {
    const apiClient = useApiClient();
    const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = React.useState<PeopleListLoadingState>('initial');
    const [data, setData] = React.useState<PeopleListData>({
        totalCount: 0,
        pageCount: -1,
        rows: [],
    });

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setLoadingState('loading');
        (async () => {
            const response = await apiClient.GET('/api/people', {
                params: {
                    query: requestQueryParams,
                },
            });

            handleResponse(response, {               
                successHandler: (data) => {
                    setLoadingState('success');
                    setData({
                        pageCount: data.pageMetadata?.totalPages ?? 0,
                        totalCount: data.pageMetadata?.totalElements ?? 0,
                        rows: data?.items ?? [],
                    });
                },
                errorHandler: () => {
                    setLoadingState('error');
                },
            });
            return;
        })();
    }, [requestQueryParams]);

    return {
        loadingState,
        data,
    };
}
```

Everything works fine in browser, but now I want to write unit test. I use Vitest and @testing-library/react. I also use MSW for request interception.

My test looks like this:

```js
 const { result } = renderHook(
            () =>
                usePeopleListAPIService({ requestQueryParams}),
            {
                wrapper: ProvidersWrapper,
            }
        );

    await waitFor(() => {
        expect(result.current.data).toEqual({
            totalCount: peopleEndpointResponse.pageMetadata.totalElements,
            pageCount: peopleEndpointResponse.pageMetadata.totalPages,
            rows: peopleEndpointResponse.items,
        });
    });

    await waitFor(() => {
        expect(result.current.loadingState).toEqual('success');
    });
```

While the first assertion passes without problems there is some problem with the second one. It never passes and there appears to be lot of rerendering happening. The state itself appears to be set accordingly inside the hook, but the return value of loadingState does not change over time in this testing environment. How is this possible ?

I use version 14.1.2 of @testing-library/react and version 0.34.6 o vitest

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: hmm...shouldn't `loadingState = "success"` in the same tick as `data` has the right results?  Why await then await again?

Comment: @MattMorgan Split it betweeen two await blocks was something I tried when I saw it doesn't work inside one. I thought maybe react did not batch updates and I have to wait a bit more for the return value of loadingState to update. Nope, neither of these solutions work.

Comment: What is the value of `result.current.loadingState` inside the first assertion then?

Comment: @MattMorgan its still "loading", as if the setState did not happen.

Comment: I suggest asserting the value of the entire `current` field (instead of just `data` or `loading`) for debugging. It seems very unlikely that your data is correct and that your loading state is not, since they're set in the same callback.  My guess is this has something to do with the way that `waitFor` is retrying the callback, and the async nature of the call.

Comment: @MattMorgan, thank you, you are right - asserting the entire current field does the thing. I dont have a clue why (I would expect everything inside the waitFor block to execute synchronously and thus checking against the same values), but at least the tests are green now!